# PHP for inner loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, insert

I have 2 arrays, the first array was working as expected (looping through the array updating the db with all elements inserted) But I added a second array that has a value I basically wanted this value to merge to the output of array 1 (I use this to add to the db, it's a string value). This is driven by a form so only rows that are selected should be added.

so array 1 is item, description... and array 2 is hashtag added

I would like for only rows that are selected (item1, description1, hashtag1.. item4, description4, hashtag4 ... item5, description5, hashtag5 if we selected rows 1,4 and 5... it could be rows 7,8,9,10 or 1,2,3... all depends)

My code outputs like (hashtag1, item1, description1 and hashtag1, item4, description4 and hashtag1, item5, description5... hashtag2, item1, description1 and hashtag2, item4, description4 and hashtag2, item5, description5 so on... repeating hashtag for each loop 3 times this case)

So instead of 3 times it is 9 times repeating the same hashtag 3 times

```
$checked = $_POST['check'];
$changed = $_POST['hashtag'];

$finalArray;
$changedVal;   

$count = count($changed);
$count2 = count($checked);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    if (!empty($changed[$i]) 
        && isset($changed[$i]) 
        && !is_null($changed[$i])) 
    {

        echo "<br>" . "it happens" . "<br>";

        for ($jj =0; $jj < $count2; $jj++) {
            $resultVal = $changed[$i] . "&&&" . $checked[$jj];
            $unbinditem = array_pad(explode("&&&",$resultVal), 5, null);
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.  Please edit your question and clarify it

Comment: Sorry about that, I have an array that is populated using the post data, this data(which is only items selected with a checkbox on the previous form) then creates a string and array pads the value so I can use each element when I insert to the db. But I added a separate field on the earlier form I manually enter a value called hashtag and want this merged in each string for the existing process of the first array inserting to the db... instead the loop multiplies the result by each item I selected with the checkbox on the earlier form and doesn't match each row values.